# Unable to upgrage Azure IoT hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

When trying to upgrade Azure IoT hub to a paid tier I get the following screen which does not make sense. I am already on a free tier. How can upgrading to a higher tier then be seen as downgrading and not allowed?

[image]

I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-upgrade) help but the screen on Azure Portal looks different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the screeshot you post, your IOT hub is Free edition.
Unfortunately,

> **you cannot switch from Free to one of the paid editions. The free edition is meant to test out proof-of-concept solutions only.**

You can see this [FAQ in the Pricing of Azure IoT Hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/iot-hub/).

[image]